# Convert hex string to long

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, hex

Are there any Cocoa classes that will help me convert a hex value in a NSString like `0x12FA` to a `long` or `NSNumber`?  It doesn't look like any of the classes like `NSNumberFormatter` support hex numbers.

Thanks,
Hua-Ying

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870475, which is about converting the hex digits to *a string*.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's a short example of how you would do it using NSScanner:

```
NSString* pString = @"0xDEADBABE";
NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: pString];

unsigned int iValue;
[pScanner scanHexInt: &iValue];
```

Answer (score 11):

See [NSScanner's](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000159-scanHexInt_) scanHex...: methods. That'll get you the primitive that you can wrap in an NSNumber.

Answer (score 7):

here is the other way conversion,  a long long int to hex string.
first the hex to long long.

```
NSString* pString = @"ffffb382ddfe";
NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: pString];

unsigned long long iValue2;
[pScanner scanHexLongLong: &iValue2];

NSLog(@"iValue2 = %lld", iValue2);
```

and the other way,  longlong to hex string...

```
NSNumber *number;
NSString *hexString;

number = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:iValue2];
hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%qx", [number longLongValue]];

NSLog(@"hexString = %@", hexString);
```