# Convert contents of NSString to bytes they represent

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString (hex) to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501033/nsstring-hex-to-bytes)

I'm currently stuck trying to convert the contents of a `NSString` to a byte.

My program receives a string, for example `CC` to a byte `0xCC`

I understand that you can convert an `NSString` to its hex representation, but this isn't what I need, as that uses the string encoding -- my `CC` would turn out as `0x63`.

From what I understand, I need to cast the `NSString` (or `char`) to a raw byte, so that I can then later on convert it to a decimal but i'm getting really confused on how to do it.

Comment: So you receive a string which contains just hex characters (i.e. 0-9 A-F) and want to convert it to byte(s)? So `"CC"` => `0xCC` and `"ABCD"` => `0xAB 0xCD`?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you mean but

```
NSData *bytes = [@"hello" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

would create a byte array.

Comment: Its ok, found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874910/convert-hex-string-to-long

Comment: No, that just converts the characters to data in that encoding. That doesn't decode hexadecimal.

Comment: I know now. The question was too incoherent for me to completely understand what he was asking.