# I would like to ask how to convert hex NSString to long value

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, hex

for example i want to covert this to long

NSString *str = @"FFFF00FF";

thanks!

Comment: check this link [Convert hex string to long][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874910/convert-hex-string-to-long

Comment: check it my answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one

```
NSString *str = @"FFFF00FF";
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: str];

unsigned long long longValue;
[scanner scanHexLongLong: &longValue];
NSLog(@"LongValue = %lld", longValue);
```

i hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
long *longString = [YourString longLongValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"FFFF00FF";

long longstring=[str longLongValue];

NSLog(@"%ld",longstring);
```

try this one.mightbe help ful to you.